# How Java Enum is different then C++ and othere conventional Enum?

Tags: java, enums

How the enum that we get from java 1.5  is different from C++ and other conventional Enum Type.

Comment: do you mean enums in UML with "conventional enum type"?

Comment: There is a very good description of ENUM type in different languages on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages)

Answer (score 5):

In java enums are complex objects, whilst in C++ every enum object is associated with a single integer value. In java you can have several attributes associated with a single enum value:

```
enum MyCategory {
   SPORT("The sport category", "sport.png"),
   NEWS("the news category", "news.jpg");

   private String description;
   private String iconPath;

   private MyCategory(String description, String iconPath) {
       this.description = description;
       this.iconPath = iconPath;
   }

   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }

   public String getIconPath() {
       return iconPath;
   }
}
```

Furthermore in java you can `switch` only Number types, Strings and enums. However I can not generalize the conventional enums as a whole...

**EDIT** One more thing the java enums can do is declare per-value operation (taken from the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)):

```
public enum Operation {
  PLUS   { double eval(double x, double y) { return x + y; } },
  MINUS  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x - y; } },
  TIMES  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x * y; } },
  DIVIDE { double eval(double x, double y) { return x / y; } };

  // Do arithmetic op represented by this constant
  abstract double eval(double x, double y);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java programming language `enums` are far more powerful than their counterparts in other languages, which are little more than glorified integers. The new enum declaration defines a full-fledged class (dubbed an enum type). In addition to solving all the problems(*Not typesafe, No namespace, Brittleness and Printed values are uninformative*) that exists with following `int Enum pattern` which was used prior to java 5.0 :

```
public static final int SEASON_WINTER = 0;
```

it also allows you to add arbitrary methods and fields to an enum type, to implement arbitrary interfaces, and more. Enum types provide high-quality implementations of all the Object methods. They are `Comparable` and `Serializable`, and the serial form is designed to withstand arbitrary changes in the enum type.

Read the full article [Java Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) for more details.