# declaring instance keyword in java

Tags: java

I see a "instance" keyword being declared in my java code declaration of a ENUM.Can someone explain how this keyword works?

Java code:-

```
public enum TodoDao {
    instance;

    private Map<String, Todo> contentProvider = new HashMap<String, Todo>();

    private TodoDao() {
        Todo todo = new Todo("1", "Learn REST");
        todo.setDescription("Read http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html");
        contentProvider.put("1", todo);
        todo = new Todo("2", "Do something");
        todo.setDescription("Read complete http://www.vogella.com");
        contentProvider.put("2", todo);
    }
    public Map<String, Todo> getModel(){
        return contentProvider;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I dont see instance anywhere.  Also the keyword is `instanceof`

Comment: That's not a keyword, it's a constant.

Answer (score 9):

It is the best way to implement the GoF singleton pattern, according to Joshua Bloch, see related question:
[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

According to the java style guide, it should be all caps, though, i.e. `INSTANCE`.

To use this, you can call the following from any part of the code:

```
Map<String, Todo> todos = TodoDao.INSTANCE.getModel();
```

And you can be certain that the initialization will happen only once.

Comment: this response deserves the first place!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a keyword. It's an enum constant, which should be in caps. You should be able to find that wherever you are learning Java from.

It's actually a really bad idea to have mutable statics like this. Also returning a mutable internal object is bad.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you  use an `enum` instead of a class if you know the number of instances in advance.

Enum use to serve  as a type of fixed number of constants :

Eg.

```
public enum TodoDao {
    INSTANCE
};
```

INSTANCE is public static final fields of TodoDao class, and like all static fields they can be accessed by class name like

> TodoDao b1 = TodoDao.INSTANCE;

Here INSTANCE is final static inner classes .

Read more:[What's the use of "enum" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850525/whats-the-use-of-enum-in-java)